# How to Fix Header's Problem of Appendix in LaTeX?

Tags: margins, appendix, header

How to enter the header of appendix in order to it doesn't hit the margin page?

I have this code on LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Lampiran}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Lampiran}

\begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Penurunan dari perkiraan solusi analitik untuk opsi Asia dengan volatilitas stokastik}
        \lipsum
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: You can provide a short version of the chapter title: `\chapter[Penurunan dari perkiraan solusi analitik]{Penurunan dari perkiraan solusi analitik untuk opsi Asia dengan volatilitas stokastik}`

Comment: You may also take the chapter name down in the continued text pages: `\chapter*{Penurunan dari perkiraan solusi analitik untuk opsi Asia dengan volatilitas stokastik}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `book` and `report` classes the `chapter` command can take an optional argument:

```
\chapter[<toc-header-title>]{<title>}
```

where the optional `toc-header-title` is put into the ToC and the page header while `title` is used as the chapter's title in the body of the document; typically `toc-header-title` is a shortened version of `title`. If the optional argument is not used then `title` is used for all three places. Similarly for the lower level divisions like `\section` etc.

I don't know the language you are using so I cannot suggest a shortened version of your appendix title that would make sense.

If you need three different versions for the ToC, header and body
the `memoir` class (a superset of `report` and `book`) extends this by providing two optional argumants:

```
\chapter[<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}
```

*No optional argument* `title` used in all three places

*One optional argument* `toc-title` used for the ToC and header

*Two optional arguments* `toc-title` used for the ToC and `head-title` used for the header.

In all cases `title` is used as the chapter's title in the body of the document.

Similarly for `\section` and below.